# ionic-gulp-browserify-typescript: What version of typescript is used?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I created an Ionic project with Typescript as below.

`ionic start MyIonic2Project tutorial --v2 --ts`

In `gulpfile.js` which is created automatically, `ionic-gulp-browserify-typescript` is used to compile Typescript.

My question is what version of typescript is used by `ionic-gulp-browserify-typescript`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ionic-gulp-browserify-typescript` uses the `tsify` plugin internally, which maintains it's own TypeScript version. As of right now, this is `1.8.7`, but that's likely to change, so you should keep an eye on the `package.json` or [npm page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsify).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will check it.